# Python by Example Book: url_patterns syntax deprecated

Tags: python, django

In setting up Login and Logout url patterns, the book (which I believe uses Django 1.8) cites:

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from . import views

url(r'^login/$', 'django.contrib.auth.views.login', name='login'),
url(r'^logout/$', 'django.contrib.auth.views.logout', name='logout'),
url(r'^logout-then-login/$','django.contrib.auth.views.logout_then_login',name='logout_then_login'),
```

where login, logout and logout_then_login have corresponding .html files in the same app template/account directory. However, on Django 1.11, these give errors of:

"TypeError: view must be a callable or a list/tuple in the case of include()"

which I believe is because this syntax is now deprecated for 1.10 and above). Tried:

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from django.contrib.auth import views as auth_views
from . import views

url(r'^login/$', auth_views.LoginView.as_view(template_name='registration/login.html')),
url(r'^logout/$', auth_views.LogoutView.as_view(template_name='registration/logged_out.html')),
url(r'^logout-then-login/$', auth_views.LogoutThenLogin.as_view(template_name='logout_then_login.html')),
```

instead, but now getting "no reverse match" errors in my main "base.html" code, at the:

```
<a href="{% url "login" %}">Log-in</a>
```

line in:

```
{% load staticfiles %}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>{% block title %}{% endblock %}</title>
    <link href="{% static "css/base.css" %}" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
    <div id="header">
        <span class="logo">Bookmarks</span>
        {% if request.user.is_authenticated %}
        <ul class="menu">
            <li {% if section == "dashboard" %}class="selected"{% endif %}><a href="{% url "dashboard" %}">My dashboard</a></li>
            <li {% if section == "images" %}class="selected"{% endif %}><a href="#">Images</a></li>
            <li {% if section == "people" %}class="selected"{% endif %}><a href="#">People</a></li>
        </ul>
        {% endif %}

        <span class="user">
        {% if request.user.is_authenticated %}
            Hello {{ request.user.username }}, <a href="{% url "logout" %}">Logout</a>
        {% else %}
            <a href="{% url "login" %}">Log-in</a>
        {% endif %}
        </span>
    </div>

    <div id="content">
        {% block content %}
        {% endblock %}
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

which didn't occur before in the earlier version of the code in the book, which used a local 'login.html' view pointed at by:

```
url(r'^login/$', views.user_login, name='login'),
```

and used exactly the same html code. FWIW, I have the project settings.py file set with:

```
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse_lazy

LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = reverse_lazy('dashboard')  # redirect after login if no next parameter
LOGIN_URL = reverse_lazy('login')               # redirect to login if login_required decorator set
LOGOUT_URL = reverse_lazy('logout')             # redirect user to logout
```

Any ideas why the url "login" can't be reversed here?

Comment: You still need the name parameters, like you had in the original version.

Comment: Thank you - I couldn't see them in the new syntax - will have another read.

Answer (score 0):

Yes Daniel was 100% correct. There is room for the namespace in the new syntax, vis:

```
    url(r'^login/$', auth_views.LoginView.as_view(template_name='registration/login.html'), name='login'),
    url(r'^logout/$', auth_views.LogoutView.as_view(template_name='registration/logged_out.html'), name='logout'),
```

With that, everything works. Thank you. I'll post this back to the publishers errata sheet.